# How to creat an array that includes multiples elements from an object from the local Storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I would like to creat an array that includes every products id's from the local storage object of my shopping website cart. The thing is the function that i made generate an array for each product's id instead of one array with all the product's id in it

```
 var cartStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
        cartStorage.forEach(function (cart, index) {
        let cartIds = [cart._id];
        console.log(cartIds); // logs one array for each id instead of just one array with every id's
       });
```

I've been trying for hours but nothing seems to work, i'm guessing i have to use a forEach() but i can't make that work?

Comment: Saving an entire cart in just one propery of the localStorage will end up by throwing an exception for some exceeded limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are defining `let cartIds` *inside* the loop. It gets created and recreated in every loop. So, of course, it contains only one element. Define it *outside* the loop, and in the loop, push stuff in it.

```
const cartStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
let cartIds = [];
cartStorage.forEach(cart => cartIds.push(cart._id));
console.log(cartIds);
```

Or even better :

```
const cartStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
const cartIds = cartStorage.map(cart => cart._id);
console.log(cartIds);
```

Also, note that, if you have no "cart" in your localStorage, `getItem` will return `null`, and your code will crash. You need to handle this case.

Answer (score 1):

Create the variable outside of the loop, and push the values into this array.

```
 var cartIds = []
 var cartStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"));
    cartStorage.forEach(function (cart, index) {
     cartIds.push(cart._id)
   });
 console.log(cartIds) // this has all the pushed values inside
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. Thank you so much for saving me so many more hours